# Redirect to last browser history location in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on my personal React project.
The React app has a login page. After successfully logging in, the user is redirected to homepage i.e. on path / . And if the user again tries to navigate to login page i.e.  path
*/login* , then the user will be redirected back to homepage

The app also has protected route on path */profile* which is accessible only if the user is authenticated.

But the problem is, when the user navigates to protected route and then refreshes the page, it is redirecting to the  homepage.
How can I make it redirect back to the same protected route from where the user had refreshed?

Here is Login.js

```
// Login.js
      if (isUserLoggedIn) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      }
      // else render login page
```

And here is ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router";

export default function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  
  const { isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.common);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        !isUserLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Component {...props} />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

And this is how I'm getting the value of isUserLoggedIn  from cookies and then setting it to the Redux state.

```
 const [authenticated] = useState(() =>
    Boolean(Number(Cookies.get("isUserLoggedIn")))
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authenticated) {
      return dispatch({
        type: NOT_AUTHENTICATED,
      });
    } else {
      return dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATED,
      });
    }
  }, [authenticated]);
```

Comment: How are you persisting your Redux state? How are you initializing your redux store when the app loads?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please read the bottom section of the post.

Comment: Thank you. I've left an answer below with what I believe is the issue and a solution. It may help to also add your `common` reducer/slice to your question so it's clear what that slice of state looks like and what its initial value is.

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms, you will have to make the browser remember that the user is now authenticated. That can be simply achieved by adding a specific `token` or `isValid = true` to the session storage and then you will have to use the value from session storage as your reference.

Updating user status in the state cannot persist it on reload. You would have to use `persistor` then. However, the easier way is to update session storage.

You can create a new JS file, say `session.js` and create the following functions:

```
export const setToken = (value) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', value)
}

export const getToken = () => {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('token') || null
}

export const removeToken = () => {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token')
}
```

You can call `setToken(true)` on successful authentication and remove the token `removeToken()` on log out. You can then call `getToken()` to check your user's authentication in your `if` statement. I hope it helps!

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: How can I use session storage, or persistor in React app?

Comment: I have explained it in detail now. Check.

Comment: Wow ! 
This looks interesting. 
I didn't know about session storage.

I'll try and see if it helps. :D 
Thank you for your valuable answer.

Comment: But, I have a doubt. 
My login component has the following lines of code which redirects the user back to the homepage is the user is already logged in.

if (isUserLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

What should I set as the value of  'to' prop in the Redirect component? So that it will redirect back to the profile page?

Comment: You should put the route of your profile page here. Have you not named it yet?

Comment: Besides, you profile page should be in the ProtectedRoute

Comment: I want the to prop of redirect component to be dynamic. 
Profile isn't the only ProtectedRoute. It has many other protected routes. And the login component must redirect the user back to where the user came from.
For eg. /profile and /create-post are two protected routes. And if I'm on /create-post route and I try to navigate to /login, then I must be redirected back to /create-post. 
And similar for /profile route too. 

What should I pass to the 'to' prop of the Redirect component, in order to make the redirect dynamic accordingly with where the user came from.

Comment: You can use useLocation hook to understand where the user came from. In your Private Route, you can use  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} /> instead of simple pathname only. And then, in your login, you can access location.state from useLocation Hook. That state can be used for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It happened same with me. I have solved this problem by using a variable that will be in Local storage so when siging in also set localstorage variable  isLogged to true `localStorage.setItem("isLogged", true)` so in case he is already logged and refreshed the page the user will redirected to profile page.
The switch statement is used bacause we get string value from localstorage and we have to convert it to boolean

```
function App() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("isLogged");
  let auth = null;
  switch (token) {
    case "true":
      auth = true;
      break;
    case "false":
      auth = false;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }}
```

as the code above you can now pass the variable auth to the component in protected route like this

```
<PrivateRoute
          path="/main"
          component={Main}
          isAuthenticated={auth}
        ></PrivateRoute>
```

and in the Private Route Component add the isAuthenticated props

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

This is the Login Component

```
const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  async function onSubmit(data) {
    try {
      await signin(data.userName, data.password);
      localStorage.setItem("isLogged", true);
      toast.success("Registerd successfully");
      history.go("/main");
    } catch {
      toast.error("Error");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <img src={Logo} alt="logo" className="logo-img"></img>
      <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form-items">
        {({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="userName">
              {({ input }) => (
                <TextField
                  name="userName"
                  type="input"
                  id="standard-basic"
                  label="user Name"
                  variant="standard"
                  fullWidth
                  {...input}
                />
              )}
            </Field>
            <Field name="password">
              {({ input }) => (
                <TextField
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  id="standard-basic"
                  label="Password"
                  variant="standard"
                  fullWidth
                  {...input}
                />
              )}
            </Field>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              sx={{
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(56, 211, 159, 255)",
                marginTop: "40px",
                color: "white",
              }}
            >
              Login
            </Button>
            <div>
              Don't Have an Account <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show me your Login component?

Comment: sure I will edit it

Comment: But your login page will still be rendered, even if the user is already authenticated.
The login page must not be accessible if the user is already logged in. 
When you're already logged in, and  you try to visit login page, it must redirect you back to where you came from.

Comment: no if it's already logged login page will not be rendered I have configured Public Routes as well so it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You are using Redux, but don't appear to load your auth state from persisted storage and instead use a mounting `useEffect` hook to dispatch an action with an auth status read from an `isUserLoggedIn` cookie.

`useEffect` runs *at the end* of the initial render cycle, so during the initial render the `isUserLoggedIn` is likely a falsey default initial reducer value.

In this case your `ProtectedRoute` component should wait until the `isUserLoggedIn` state is *actually* populated.

```
export default function ProtectedRoute(props) {
  const { isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.common);

  if (isUserLoggedIn === undefined) { // or whatever the default, indeterminant value is
    return null; // or loading indicator, etc...
  }

  return isUserLoggedIn ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
}
```